# Setting backgroundColor of relative layout

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, background-color

I'm trying to set a relative layout's background with,

```
relativeLayout1.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
```

My program keeps crashing though. Here's the [logcat](http://pastebin.com/3YBGkLiP).

Code:

```
RelativeLayout window=(RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.window);
window.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
```

That's the only stuff apart from the regular code `setContentView(R.layout.something);` and `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`

Entire code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_invisible);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
    window=(RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.window);
        window.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
}
```

Comment: Post your code from `onStart` in your brightnessService.

Comment: @Ralgha - I've changed the pastebin link. That was the wrong logcat.

Comment: If you'll let us know what's on line 45 (pointed to on your logcat), that would certainly help. Also just a tip, you might want to use `Color.TRANSPARENT` instead of 0x00000000, from [Android Dev Site](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#TRANSPARENT)

Comment: Post your onCreate method from your activity

Comment: @dymmeh There, I've put up the entire code.

Comment: Can we see your xml layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was another of Eclipse's moments. It didn't compile my code, so I was executing the old code. Restarted Eclipse and my app works fine now.

Answer (score 1):

From the logcat attached, I can say that most likely your `window` pointer is `null` at the time you are trying to set background color. It can be caused by different types of problems:

- Your `something.xml` layout does **NOT** contain element with `android:id="@+id/window"` attribute
- Your `something.xml` layout **DOES** contain element with `android:id="@+id/window"` attribute, but this element is not `RelativeLayout`
- Your project resource data got messed up. Try to do Project->Clean to rebuild resources

Comment: I've tried everything you listed. There is a Relative layout with the id window in something.xml, I cleaned the project. Nothing. Still crashes.

Comment: could you post the line #45 from your InvisibleActivity file? Apparently the problem is there

Comment: I did. It's this - `relativeLayout1.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);`

Answer (score 0):

Is there is your `R.layout.something` a layout with the id `R.id.window` ?

Maybe you've missed something?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this instead
relative layout.setBackgroundDrawable(get resources().get drawable(R.drawable.bg);

Or you could define it in XML
android: background="@drawable/bg"